# How to fix psycopg2 error when setting up PsiTurk on Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, psycopg2, heroku-postgres

I am following https://psiturk.readthedocs.io/en/latest/heroku.html to set up psiturk on Heroku. Deployed successfully, but then it runs into Internal Server Error after clicking "Begin by viewing the ad.". 
It looks like the error comes from

> ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) WITHIN GROUP is required
>   for ordered-set aggregate mode

Tried tweeking requirements.txt like `psycopg2`, or `psycopg2==2.7.7`, no difference... very little experience with this stack here.

Here is more complete log:

```
2019-03-27T03:34:30.149079+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-03-27 03:34:30,148] ERROR in app: Exception on /ad [GET]
2019-03-27T03:34:30.149099+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2019-03-27T03:34:30.149102+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
2019-03-27T03:34:30.149103+00:00 app[web.1]: response = self.full_dispatch_request()
.......
2019-03-27T03:34:30.149176+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 552, in do_execute
2019-03-27T03:34:30.149177+00:00 app[web.1]: cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
2019-03-27T03:34:30.149178+00:00 app[web.1]: ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) WITHIN GROUP is required for ordered-set aggregate mode
2019-03-27T03:34:30.149180+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 2: ...rkdemo_bonus, turkdemo.status AS turkdemo_status, turkdemo.m...
2019-03-27T03:34:30.149181+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2019-03-27T03:34:30.149182+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-03-27T03:34:30.149183+00:00 app[web.1]: [SQL: SELECT count(*) AS count_1
2019-03-27T03:34:30.149194+00:00 app[web.1]: FROM (SELECT turkdemo.uniqueid AS turkdemo_uniqueid, turkdemo.assignmentid AS turkdemo_assignmentid, turkdemo.workerid AS turkdemo_workerid, turkdemo.hitid AS turkdemo_hitid, turkdemo.ipaddress AS turkdemo_ipaddress, turkdemo.browser AS turkdemo_browser, turkdemo.platform AS turkdemo_platform, turkdemo.language AS turkdemo_language, turkdemo.cond AS turkdemo_cond, turkdemo.counterbalance AS turkdemo_counterbalance, turkdemo.codeversion AS turkdemo_codeversion, turkdemo.beginhit AS turkdemo_beginhit, turkdemo.beginexp AS turkdemo_beginexp, turkdemo.endhit AS turkdemo_endhit, turkdemo.bonus AS turkdemo_bonus, turkdemo.status AS turkdemo_status, turkdemo.mode AS turkdemo_mode, turkdemo.datastring AS turkdemo_datastring
2019-03-27T03:34:30.149195+00:00 app[web.1]: FROM turkdemo
2019-03-27T03:34:30.149196+00:00 app[web.1]: WHERE turkdemo.assignmentid != %(assignmentid_1)s AND turkdemo.workerid = %(workerid_1)s) AS anon_1]
2019-03-27T03:34:30.149198+00:00 app[web.1]: [parameters: {'assignmentid_1': u'debug8OzHL', 'workerid_1': u'debug8chrG'}]
2019-03-27T03:34:30.149199+00:00 app[web.1]: (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/f405)
```

Anyone suggestions appreciated!